# show result data on client in that data store in decimal 128?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, aggregate

There is a data store with a decimal number when pulling it from the database in a decimal 128 and how can I show it on a client.

how convert data decimal128 to number?

```
{_bsontype: "Decimal128", bytes: Uint8Array(16)}
 bytes: Uint8Array(16)
_bsontype: "Decimal128"
__ob__: Observer {value: {…}, dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
get bytes: ƒ reactiveGetter()
set bytes: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
get _bsontype: ƒ reactiveGetter()
set _bsontype: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
__proto__: Object
```

[result show on client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWdhl.png)

Comment: How is this related to the `meteor` tag? Please add more information about where the data comes from, how you retrieve it in the client and some code on how you tried to display it (and errors, if it failed).

Comment: this is my code call method `getData() {
      findStudentByScore
        .callPromise()
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res.score)          
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
        })
    },`     But my score Field is Decimal Number. How can I access value form score?

Comment: Please don't add code into comments, as it makes it even harder to get an idea of what the problem is. Rather you may edit your question and append it with code.

Comment: Sorry I try to display value of score that it store in data type decimal

Comment: This is a really low level view of the data. I think your question isn't really about Meteor, it's just a number formatting problem, which is probably answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript equivalent to printf/String.Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format)

Comment: It is not just print before print we need to access data property score that data type is numberDecimal